# How to generate random data, that's from Beta distribution with specific density function in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, beta-distribution, histogram

So, considering that $\theta = 2$ and density function is $f(x) = \theta x^{\theta - 1},   0<x<1$ and $0$ anywhere else, how do I generate random data from this particular distribution? 
Here is the code I tried:

```
x <- rbeta(10000, 1, 2)                              
hist(x)                                                        
curve(dbeta(x, 1, 2), add = TRUE)
```

First, I don't know if I can generate the data using functon rbeta as my density function is not exactly like ordinary Beta distribution?
Then, when I try to add theoretical distribution's curve, it doesn't appear at all in the region of the histogram, and if I plot it separately it is just a straight line nut a skewed curve like it should be. What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain the function $f(x) = \theta x^{\theta - 1}$ you need to use `rbeta( , 2, 1)`, not `rbeta( , 1, 2)` (to see why look into `?rbeta`).

```
density_fun <- function(x,theta=2){
  theta * x^(theta-1)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
x <- rbeta(10000, 2, 1)                              
hist(x, freq=F, col="grey", border="white",main="rbeta(10000, 2, 1)", xlab="x", ylab="f(x)")              
curve(dbeta(x, 2, 1), add = TRUE,lwd=2)

x = seq(0, 1, length.out=500)
plot(x,density_fun(x),col="red", type="l",xlab="x", ylab="f(x)", main=expression(paste(f(x) == theta * x^(theta-1),", with ",theta==2)),lwd=2)
```

Result:
[image]
Note that you need to plot the histogram using the argument `freq=F` to plot bars on a probability density scale

As you can see, the function is indeed a straight line; it should not be a curve since for $\theta=2$ you have that $f(x) = 2 x^{2 - 1} = 2x$

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reply, just wanted to ask, if I were to use the density_fun as an argument for a curve function, would that still be considered a theoretical density line, or is it better to use rbeta as it doesn't take into the consideration the density function given? I know this probably is dumb, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: In this case they are equivalent; `density_fun` is a proper density function since its integral (over the support [0,1]) is 1.